# Google Map: How can I select multiple markers, which I imported, by clicking or drawing a shape around them?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gis, kml

I created a map with Google Map Maker. I did so by imported 5 different Excel files that had address fields and saved them all as different layers. The map now has about 500 addresses which are marked with pins that are color coded to the layer they belong with.

Is there anyway I can either use the "Draw Line" tool or another means to select a group of those markers/pins? Ideally I am envisioning being able to draw a shape around them and then being able to select those address to save them as a new data table or layer to export back to Excel.

Does anyone know of a way to achieve this? Even if it is another product then Google Maps? Thank you so much any help would be a life saver.

Comment: The answer is "probably". What does your code look like?  How are you adding the markers to the map?  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates what you currently have.

Comment: I do not have a code. All I have is a normal Google Map which I made from Google Map Maker. I thought I did describe it well, I imported 5 different Excel files with address fields, which Google Map then marks. 

Why downvote and be so negative instead of helpful? It really bums me out. I took all this time to write a clear and explained question and then get downvoted and told I am unclear.

Comment: @user3745883: Don't take downvotes personally -- they're merely a tool to help you. When one of your questions gets downvoted, you should edit/improve the original, and not ask a new question (this one is a duplicate and will probably be deleted). The issue with your question is that you're asking a broad one with a yes/no answer, but also asking that a full solution be implemented, when you've shown no effort on your own behalf. That makes the question too broad as it stands. This is not a reflection of you or your abilities, but perhaps this question is just not a great fit for SO.