# Google Map: How can I select multiple markers, which I imported, by clicking or drawing a shape around them and save them as a Data Table?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gis, kml

I created a map with Google Map Maker. I did so by imported 5 different Excel files that had address fields and saved them all as different layers. The map now has about 500 addresses which are marked with pins that are color coded to the layer they belong with. I have no code per say, just the my Google Map which I created.

Is there anyway I can either use the "Draw Line" tool or another means to select a group of those markers/pins? Ideally I am envisioning being able to draw a shape around them and then being able to select those address to save them as a new data table or layer to export back to Excel.

Does anyone know of a way to achieve this? Even if it is another product then Google Maps? Thank you so much any help would be a life saver.

Comment: duplicate of [Google Map: How can I select multiple markers, which I imported, by clicking or drawing a shape around them?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33205270/google-map-how-can-i-select-multiple-markers-which-i-imported-by-clicking-or)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to draw a route between two markers in Google Maps API?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19854072/how-to-draw-a-route-between-two-markers-in-google-maps-api)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this.

```
<head>
  <style>
    html, body, #map-canvas {
      height: 400px;
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px
    }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry"></script>    
  <script>
    var random_marker_locations = [
      new google.maps.LatLng(50.7, 4.1),
      new google.maps.LatLng(50.4, 4.2),
      new google.maps.LatLng(50.1, 4.3),
      new google.maps.LatLng(50.8, 4.4),
      new google.maps.LatLng(50.5, 4.5),
      new google.maps.LatLng(50.2, 4.6),
      new google.maps.LatLng(50.9, 4.7),
      new google.maps.LatLng(50.6, 4.8),
      new google.maps.LatLng(50.3, 4.9)
    ]

    var map;
    var markers = [];
    var polygon;
    var polygonMarkers = [];
    var polygonLocations = [];

    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 8,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(50.40, 4.34),  // Brussels, Belgium
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    function initialize() {
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
      // add markers
      for(var i in random_marker_locations) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: random_marker_locations[i], map: map, title: 'marker ' + i});
        markers.push(marker);
      }

      // add a click on map event
      google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {
        // set a marker there, with a small measle icon
        var position = e.latLng;
        polygonLocations.push(position);
        polygonMarkers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
          icon: 'https://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_ALL/mapfiles/markers2/measle.png',
          position: position, 
          map: map
        }));
        // now let's add a polygon
        drawPolygon(polygonLocations);
      });
    }

    // draws a polygon
    function drawPolygon(points) {
      if(points.length < 3) {
        return;
      }
      // first delete the previous polygon
      if(polygon) {
        polygon.setMap(null);
      }
      // @see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polygon-simple
      polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
        paths: points,
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: '#FF0000',
        fillOpacity: 0.35,
        map: map
      });
      // display to input
      displaySelectedMarkers(polygon);
    }
    // display the selected markers to input.  
    function displaySelectedMarkers(polygon) {
      // empty the input
      document.getElementById('selected_markers').value = '';
      var a=0;  // I use this to set a comma between the values, but no comma at the end
      for(var i in random_marker_locations) {
        // @see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/poly-containsLocation
        if (google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(random_marker_locations[i], polygon)) {
          document.getElementById('selected_markers').value += (a++>0 ? ', ' : '') + i ;
        }
      }
    }

    function clearSelection() {
      if(polygon) {
        polygon.setMap(null);
      }
      for (var i in polygonMarkers) {
        polygonMarkers[i].setMap(null);
      }          
      polygonLocations = [];
      document.getElementById('selected_markers').value = '';
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  <hr>
  <input id="selected_markers"><br>
  <input type="button" onclick="clearSelection()" value="Clear polygon"><br>
  Click to select a polygon selection around the markers
</body>
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for so much for replying! Is there anyway you can point me in the direction of a guide or explain how I would go about "installing" this code? I am not too familiar with Google Maps and I guess I didn't realize you could "install" your own code into it.

Comment: You can copy paste my code to an empty .htm file, and it will run.  So if you can merge my code with your html, it should work.  Make sure you load the script file as I have.  Mind the id of the elements.  Let me know if it works.

Comment: Thank you so much. So I am like really new at this. How do I paste the code to an empty .htm file and run it?

When I created this map I did so by going to www.google.com/maps/d/ and "created a new map". I then uploaded the KLM files I have which mapped all the address with markers. Is this something I need to do in Google Earth or something?

Sorry. I hope not to bother you or come across as too much of a lost cause. Thank you again.

Comment: open notepad, paste the code that I posted. Save the file as index.htm . (if you have access to a server) Then you upload that file to a place on the server.  Locally (like if you don't have a server), you can simply right-mouse-click -> open with Chrome (or what ever browser)

Comment: Whoa. That is so awesome. Thanks a ton. So now I just need to copy my Html of My Map and merge it with your code? Can you tell me how I would do that? Sorry again. Hope not to be a bother. I do see how I can "view source" to see my maps Html code.

Comment: can you send me an e-mail? emmanueldelay@gmail.com . Stackoverflow doesn't like it when comments become a chat